# How to use exec() in nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I have this procedure `xyz_users_list` and it return list of users with `exec xyz_users_list` but how do i use it in nodejs app?

## Code

`index.js`

```
'use strict';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const mysql = require('mysql');
var connection = require('express-myconnection');
require('dotenv').config();

app.use(
    connection(mysql, {
        host: process.env.DB_HOST,
        user: process.env.DB_USERNAME,
        password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        database: process.env.DB_DATABASE
    }, 'request')
);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

//all users
var Users = require('./routes/Users');
app.get('/users', Users.list);
```

`Users.js`

```
'use strict';

var response = require('../res');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

    exports.list = function(req, res) {
        req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            connection.query(exec('xyz_users_list'), function(err, rows) {
                if (err)
                    console.log("%s ", err);

                response.success(rows, res);
            });
        });
    };
```

this code returns:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

*If I use code below it works just fine but since i want to use `exec` it's returning error.*

```
exports.list = function(req, res) {
        req.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
            connection.query('SELECT * FROM `users`', function(err, rows) {
                if (err)
                    console.log("%s ", err);

                response.success(rows, res);
            });
        });
    };
```

any idea?

## Update

here is result of my `exec xyz_users_list` in `SQLQuery`

[image: one]

Comment: what should `exec('xyz_users_list')` return ?

Comment: @C.Gochev list of users

Comment: you need to pass a `query` not a list

Comment: @C.Gochev sorry what? I have `connection.query(....`

Comment: @C.Gochev updated my question

Comment: a `sql` query you can say something like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ?` and then give an array of ids for example.

Comment: @C.Gochev yes i'm aware of that, as you see in second code of my question i've mentioned that i am able to get my users with such code, but i want to use procedure instead of that query method.

Comment: @C.Gochev if my code `connection.query(` should be changed to anything else in order to call `exce` please inform me

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is coming as undefined so it is showing this error. Try this version

```
const sql = require("mssql");

exports.list = async function(req, res) {
  const connection = await sql.connect("connectionString");
  const results = await connection.request().execute("xyz_users_list");
}
```

Need to add the corresponding return statements but you will get an idea.